# How to pass objects to methods in other classes in VB6

Tags: class, vb6

I have created two classes as interface / implementation classes, and wish to pass a particular example of one class to a method in the other. The definitions are as follows...

Class BigInt...

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub dothing(ByRef passed_object As MyInt)
End Sub
```

and an implementation BigImplementation...

```
Option Explicit
Implements BigInt

Public Sub BigInt_dothing(ByRef passed_obj As MyInt)
Dim i As Integer
i = passed_obj.getprop
End Sub
```

The class I am planning to pass is...

```
Option Explicit

Public Property Get getprop() As Integer
End Property

Public Property Let letprop(ByVal myval As Integer)
End Property
```

implemented as MyImplementation thus...

```
Option Explicit
Implements MyInt
Private myval As Integer

Public Property Get myint_getprop() As Integer
myint_getprop = myval
End Property

Public Property Let myint_letprop(ByVal passed_int As Integer)
myval = passed_int
End Property
```

I am then driving this with the following snippet of code:-

```
Private Sub Command_Click()
Dim myobj As MyInt
Set myobj = New MyImplementation
Dim mybigobj As BigInt
Set mybigobj = New BigImplementation

myobj.letprop = 1
Call mysub(myobj)
mybigobj.dothing (myobj)   ' Line with problem
End Sub

Private Sub mysub(ByVal passed_obj As MyInt)
Dim i As Integer
i = passed_obj.getprop
End Sub
```

When the execution reaches the line marked, I get run-time error 438 - Object doesn't support property or method. The call to the ordinary function mysub works perfectly. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong and what I need to do to fix this?

Comment: None of your parameters need to be `ByRef` and I would personally find them misleading e.g. my calling code would have to test whether the reference I passed `ByRef` is pointing to a different object after the call. But If it was `ByVal` I would be able to trust the callee.

Comment: @onedaywhen, good point; thank you for that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use either

```
mybigobj.dothing myobj
```

or

```
Call mybigobj.dothing(myobj)
```

Putting extra parentheses around a reference evaluates its default property and passes it's value as actual argument.

Comment: thank you. My first try suggests that's the problem. I'll check a little more thoroughly next week.

Comment: Voted this up but wanted to say I really hate stumbling over the second syntax in peoples' code. Just learn the rules, and if you pay attention the IDE even hints you when you mis-paren calls: it inserts a space before the left paren to show you what you've done.

Comment: @Bob: We found useful usage for the second syntax -- we use it when calling API functions i.e. `Call Sleep(1000)`, so to remember that `Err.LastDllError` is set :-))

Comment: Tried it out a bit more, and all splendid. Thank you, wqw.

Answer (score 0):

mybigobj.dothing requires its parameter to be a MyInt

```
Public Sub BigInt_dothing(ByRef passed_obj As MyInt)
Dim i As Integer
i = passed_obj.getprop
End Sub
```

You're passing a MyImplementation

```
Set myobj = New MyImplementation
```

So possiblly something like (my vb is rusty)

```
mybigobj.dothing (myobj.myint_getprop())
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. I tried changing the parameters in `dothing` to `ByRef passed_object as MyImplementation` but the same thing happened. I would like to pass in the whole object rather than its properties as parameters if at all possible as the object myobj provides several facts and these values may also change from time to time.

Comment: You should add a method like the one above but taking a MyImplmentation

Comment: thank you for trying, but the method eatinging a `MyImplementation` produces the same result.