# Passing information between class modules in vba

Tags: vba, class, module

What is the best way to pass information between two class modules in vba?

I think I understand the property set statements but don't know how to connect two classes as such.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4969474

Comment: Do you want one class to use the other class or something else? A bit more detail would help with knowing how to answer and the level of detail to provide.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Perhaps that link might be a little bit more advanced for but I am still unable to understand what is going on there.

Comment: @ChipsLetten Yes thank you! That is exactly what I am trying to do. I want one class to use another class and vice versa. Basically the public properties, public subs and public functions should be "inter-usable" between multiple classes. Not sure if this is possible but any help would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use them the same way you would in other code.

```
Dim variableName As className
Set variableName = New className
variableName.someMethod
Set variableName = Nothing
```

I find [Chip Pearson's web site](http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/MainPage.aspx) to be very useful. Here are some links specific to your question:

[Classes in VBA](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/classes.aspx)
[Custom Collection Classes](http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/CollectionClass.aspx)

You will need to be careful if you have objects that reference each other. [This page](http://www.vbi.org/Items/article.asp?id=106) explains it even though it is talking about classic VB. The `Deallocate` method mentioned on the page works.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I was actually already on that page. Just trying to understand the difference between class collections and interfaces. For example where I would be able to use each of them. Getting there slowly!